# How do i fix regex matching few unexpected characters?

Tags: regex, perl

i am using a regex where as a first preference i am intending to match the character ( number or alphanumeric ) immediately succeeding the string "Lecture" else match the last character of line in absence of string "Lecture".

**Curent regex**

```
cat 1.txt | perl -ne 'print "$& \n" while /Lecture\h*\K\w+|^(?!.*Lecture).*\h\K[^.\s]+/g;/^.*?-(.*)/g' | perl -ne 'print "$& \n" while /(\d+\w*)/g'
```

The data to read is not very consistent. There could be spaces or hyphen around the string "Lecture" or end character and line may not end as .mp4
My current regex is working almost well , it just having the issues for the bottom 3 lines . I could have only included those lines here but i don't want the solution regex to break for the other cases. So including all possibilities below

**cat 1.txt**

```
54282068 Lecture74- AS 29 Question.mp4   
174424104Lecture 74B - AS 29 Theory.mp4   
Branch Accounts Lecture 105
Lecture05 - Practicals AS 28
Submissions 20.mp4
HW Section 77N
Residential status HWS Q.1 to 6 -60A
Residential status HWS Q.7 to 20 -60B
House property all HWS-60C
Salary HWS Q.11 to 13 - 60F
Salary HWS Q.1 to 5-60D
Salary HWS Q.6 to 10-60E
Salary HWS Q.14 to 20-60G
Operating Costing 351
```

**Expected Output**

```
74
74B
105
05
20
77N
60A
60B
60C
60F
60D
60E
60G
351
```

**Exact Issue** - For the bottom 3 lines above the last one it is printing 5,10 and 20 additionally along with the end character 60D, 60E and 60G

I believe there's a issue in the last part of my regex somewhere, needs a very small edit to fix . Hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: `/Lecture\s*(\d+[A-Z]?)/ ||/([\dA-Z]+)\.mp4/ || /\-?[ ]?(\d+[A-Z])[ \r\n]?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please inspect following piece of code for compliance with your requirements

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    s/\.mp4//;
    say $1 if /Lecture\s*(\w+)/ or /(\d{2}[A-Z]?)\Z/;
}

__DATA__
54282068 Lecture74- AS 29 Question.mp4   
174424104Lecture 74B - AS 29 Theory.mp4   
Branch Accounts Lecture 105
Lecture05 - Practicals AS 28
Submissions 20.mp4
HW Section 77N
Residential status HWS Q.1 to 6 -60A
Residential status HWS Q.7 to 20 -60B
House property all HWS-60C
Salary HWS Q.11 to 13 - 60F
Salary HWS Q.1 to 5-60D
Salary HWS Q.6 to 10-60E
Salary HWS Q.14 to 20-60G
```

Output

```
74
74B
105
05
20
77N
60A
60B
60C
60F
60D
60E
60G
```

Comment: Thanks for answering . i would be grateful if you also include a commandline implementation of your solution like in my question .That would help me better to understand my mistake .. Also the input files would be changing each time so it would be easier for me to use cat file | perl regex each time and i don't really prefer to execute a separate perl script

Comment: In MS Windows the command is `perl -ne "s/\.mp4//; print \"$1\n\" if /Lecture\s*(\w+)/ or /(\d{2}[A-Z]?)\Z/;" 1.txt`. In UNIX/Linux/MacOSX the command is `perl -ne 's/\.mp4//; print "$1\n" if /Lecture\s*(\w+)/ or /(\d{2}[A-Z]?)\Z/;' 1.txt`.

Comment: I apologise for pointing this out a week late .i think there's a very small derp in the regex. .. if i add - ```Operating Costing 351``` as the bottom line , your regex is printing ```51``` instead of ```351``` .

Comment: @Sachin -- I see you prefer to type a very long commands, please before you press 'Enter' check what you type as this method is prone to mistakes.

Comment: @Sachin -- alter regular expression to capture required number digits, that will be all.